# PHP MySQL not always saving everything to database table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using PHP and MySQL to save coordinates into a database table. Below is the query I use.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cbmarker.annot_test 
                    (userid, project_id, image, date, coords, newLine, color, annot_type)
             VALUES (" . $userID . "," . $pid . ",'". $pic . "', NOW()," 
                       . $coordArray[0] . ", true ,'" . $drawingColor 
                       . "','" . $annotType ."')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Most of the variables come from a get request passed through javascript.

```
for(var i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++)
{
    if(lines[i] != 0)
    {
        loadJSONarray(lineCoordsBeforeConvert[i], lineColor[i], "line");    
    }
}
```

**loadJSONArray** will mediate and send the get request to my server script. I have checked and tested that in general all of the data correctly saves to the database. However, occasionally it doesn't always save and I lose some of the coordinate data. I can't seem to consistently reproduce this error. When I get the error and repeat my steps to get it again, it doesn't always happen. This leads me to believe there may be a problem with mySQL in general. Is it normal for MySQL to skip out on writing to a database? Could it be because I'm trying to pass too much data to it at one time? I want to know if anybody else has ever come across this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the logs (mysql.log or similar) and web server/web application server logs?   They may give you clues as to why the insertion got rejected/rolledback, etc...

Comment: show us `CREATE TABLE` statement for your `annot_test` table, and show us more of your php code, because you send 3 var using `loadJSONarray` in js, but we hav no idea how do you transform all these values to get your php vars: `$userID, $pid, $pic, $coordArray[0], $drawingColor, $annotType`

Comment: You should be using mysqli_query instead of mysql_query. What I would do is print mysqli_error() and run a couple of test queries.

Comment: What value is assigned to `$result`. That, in addition to the various functions to get the last error and the number of affected should guide you to the cause.

Comment: Convert from mysql_* interface to mysqli_* interface.  Check for errors after mysqli_query